# Reset _.after counter

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I looked on the internet, but I was not able to find a way of resetting the _.after counter after the code inside gets executed. In this example, my intended functionality would mean that only every 5th click on the button would show the alert box:

```
var cb;

cb = _.after(4, function() {
    alert(':)');
});

$('button').on('click', cb);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danharper/JkcuD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't reset or even see the counter because the counter is private:

from: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-87

```
 _.after = function(times, func) {
    return function() {
      if (--times < 1) {
        return func.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    };
  };
```

that said, you can see there's not much code there, so adjusting it to run once-every is easy:

```
 _.onceEvery= function(times, func) {
    var orig = times;
    return function() {
      if (--times < 1) {
        times=orig;
        return func.apply(this, arguments);
      }
    };
  };
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/JkcuD/78/